# replacement for Net Send

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, messaging, netsend

Is there any replacement for Net Send, I believe it was called, we can implement for our 60+ computers at work?
We would like the ability to :
1) send messages to all logged on users and 
2) send messages to a single user

Our environment: 
Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise
Windows 7 Pro
Windows 8 Pro
Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 8, Windows Server 2008,, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista (and I presume Windows 7, though not listed) have [*msg*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771903.aspx) command, similar to *net send*.

See also http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that command.  I receive the error message: C:\windows\system32>msg xxxx.xxxx test
xxxx.xxxx does not exist or is disconnected

Comment: Sorry about that... msg.exe is not available in some Windows versions. Nice of MS to remove NET SEND and *not* provide MSG!

Comment: There is a free third-party tool, <a href="http://www.cezeo.com/products/netsend/">cezeo *NetSend*</a>, though I've not used it.

Answer (score 0):

Get PsTools from ([technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx)).  Then you can:

```
psexec @PClist.txt cmd.exe "/C msg.exe * Message goes here"
```

Details on above command at:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/431275-sending-messages-to-all-domain-users